# Logarithmic Differentiation - Unable to get the correct answer when differentiating $y = 3x^{4x + 1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate $3x^{4x+1}$ using logarithmic differentiation.

The answer provided is as follow:
$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \left(3x^{4x+1}\right) \left(4 + \frac{1}{x} + 4\ln(x)\right) $

The answer I got is:
$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \left(3x^{4x+1}\right)\left(\left(\frac{4x+1}{x}\right) + 4\ln(\pmb{3x})\right)$

I don't know why the answer has $\ln(x)$ rather than $\ln(3x)$. I have also made the same mistake in my method in other (similar) questions, based off the answers given.

If someone could help me out I would be very appreciative! $:)$

My solution is as follows:

$y = 3x^{4x+1}$

$ \ln(y) = \ln\left(3x^{4x+1}\right)$

$\ln(y) = (4x+1)\ln(3x)$

$\frac{1}{y} \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = (4x+1)\left(\frac{1}{3x} \cdot 3\right) + \big(\ln(3x)\big)(4)$ , where I'm using the product rule to differentiate $(4x+1)\ln(3x)$

$\frac{1}{y} \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{4x+1}{x} + 4\ln(3x)$

$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = y \left(\frac{4x+1}{x} + 4\ln(3x)\right)$ where $y = 3x^{4x+1} $

$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \left(3x^{4x+1}\right) \left(\left(\frac{4x+1}{x}\right) + 4\ln(\pmb{3x})\right)$

Comment: $3x^{4x+1} \ne (3x)^{4x+1}$

Comment: As stated by player3236, you need to be careful with order of operations. $3x^{4x+1}=3\cdot x^{4x+1}$, not $(3x)^{4x+1}$

Comment: Ah I see, silly mistake. However I am still getting the wrong answer having tried to account for this. Never thought my maths would get this rusty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @player3236, $3x^{4x+1}\neq (3x)^{4x+1}$ in general.

So you should have $$\ln(y)=\ln(3x^{4x+1})=\ln(3)+\ln(x^{4x+1})=\ln(3)+(4x+1)\ln(x) 
.$$

Answer (score 0):

When you apply $ln$ on both sides in the second line of your solution, you have made a mistake when writing the power multiplied by the base of the power.
You can observe that in the question it is $3x^{4x+1}$ and not ${(3x)}^{4x+1}$.
The correct one should be:
**$ln(y) = ln(3) + (4x+1) ln(x)$**
I hope you can simplify further and arrive at the correct result !

Answer (score 0):

$y = 3x^{4x+1}$

$ lny = ln(3x^{4x+1})=ln3+ln(x^{4x+1})$

$lny = ln3+(4x+1)ln(x)$

$\frac{y'}{y}=4ln(x)+(4x+1)\times \frac{1}{x}$

${y'}=(3x^{4x+1})\times (4ln(x)+(4x+1)\times \frac{1}{x}$)